# Blender Texture pain Painting over UV lines

Tags: uv, texture-painting

[image]

I am trying to paint pixel art on this character model but the colours keep going over the designated uv and effecting other parts of the character model. is there any way to stop blender from bleeding over

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *Bleed* option in the *N* panel > *Tool > Options*:

[image]